# Are there any libraries for loading and processing/disassembling Direct3D shader bytecode?

Tags: graphics, compiler-construction, direct3d, shader

Are there any libraries for loading and processing/disassembling the Direct3D (10,11) shader bytecode files generated by fxc?

I know that many developers (and hardware vendors) have internal tools to load and process the D3D shader bytecode formats, but since the shader bytecode format is private and binary-only as of D3D10, I wonder whether there are any public resources for working with it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want the `HRESULT D3DDisassemble()` function from the DirectX SDK: https://web.archive.org/web/20110625031033/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd607326(v=VS.85).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to, or can't, use the Direct3D `D3DDisassemble` function, then there are some open source libraries available:

- [SlimShader](https://github.com/tgjones/slimshader) is an open source .NET library capable of parsing Direct3D 10/11 shader bytecode. (Disclaimer: I'm the author of SlimShader.) There is a companion project, SlimShader.VirtualMachine, which can execute the disassembled shader entirely on the CPU.
- [fxdis](https://code.google.com/p/fxdis-d3d1x/) is a C++ Direct3D bytecode disassembler.
- [HLSLCrossCompiler](https://github.com/James-Jones/HLSLCrossCompiler) is a C++ library that can parse Direct3D shader bytecode and convert it to GLSL.